# Quickly finding the size of an S3 'folder'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

We have s3 'folders' (objects with a prefix under a bucket) with millions and millions of files and we want to figure out the size of these folders.

Writing my own .net application to get the lists of s3 objects was easy enough but the maximum number of keys per request is 1000, so it's taking forever.

Using S3Browser to look at a 'folder's' properties is taking a long time too.  I'm guessing for the same reasons.

I've had this .NET application running for a week - I need a better solution.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Maximum keys per request is 1000? I'm not super familiar with the tech, are these folders remote?

Comment: Yea.  http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Comment: Do you need an exact count, or approximate? Is there any structure in the object names that would enable you to, for example, find out how many files were added between date A and date B, then extrapolate that across the whole lifetime?

Comment: Approximate would work, but it still has to be fairly accurate.  The number of objects and their sizes being put into these locations would change over time, though.  We have two years worth of objects.  I'd have to get multiple samples over time and use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the ideal solution does not exist. But I offer some ideas you can further develop:

1. Is the app the only mean by which file are written to S3? If so, you can store (in a db, a file or what ever) the files size and sum it when necessary
2. Do concurrent calls to the LIST api
3. Can you switch from an organisation based on folders to one based on buckets? If so, you could query the billing API (yes, the billing) and calculating the size (or an approximation of) from cost...

Comment: #1 doesn't apply.  Unfortunately We have too much content in there and have already reached out bucket limit to use #3

#2 is the option I've been considering, but it would still take as long as the biggest 'folder' takes, which is like 3-4 hours.

Comment: on #2: I was thinking at concurrent calls for a single folder. By using the `prefix` parameter you can have - for example - a call listing objects whose name start with 'a', one for 'b', etc...

Comment: query to billing api and calculating the size can be very sketchy while billing is affected by many options of s3 and billing. for starters think about s3 storage classes, end with billig all kind of saving plans and related "billing products".

Answer (score 31):

The [**AWS CLI**'s `ls` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html) can do this: `aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://$BUCKETNAME/$PREFIX --region $REGION`

Comment: get all the buckets info https://gist.github.com/jorgetovar/1f5e52ec4732d597e6d2bc432ee0745c

Answer (score 14):

Seems like AWS added a menu item where it's possible to see the size:

[image: size of S3 folder]

Comment: Is there a boto3 API and S3 CLI command for this? Very much needed. I know we can write codes around it but I wanted it from AWS, which wasn't there until when you posted this, but I can't see any documentation on this.

Comment: There's an answer from Foolish Brilliance for CLI but I haven't tried it: aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://$BUCKETNAME/$PREFIX --region $REGION

Comment: Is there any boto3 equivalent of the same? Strange that AWS provides a Console and CLI solution, but nothing for boto3/SDK.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer using the AWSCLI. I find that the web console often times out when there are too many objects.

- replace s3://bucket/ with where you want to start from.
- relies on awscli, awk, tail, and some bash-like shell

```sh
start=s3://bucket/ && \
for prefix in `aws s3 ls $start | awk '{print $2}'`; do
  echo ">>> $prefix <<<"
  aws s3 ls $start$prefix --recursive --summarize | tail -n2
done
```

or in one line form:

```sh
start=s3://bucket/ && for prefix in `aws s3 ls $start | awk '{print $2}'`; do echo ">>> $prefix <<<"; aws s3 ls $start$prefix --recursive --summarize | tail -n2; done
```

Output looks something like:

```sh
$ start=s3://bucket/ && for prefix in `aws s3 ls $start | awk '{print $2}'`; do echo ">>> $prefix <<<"; aws s3 ls $start$prefix --recursive --summarize | tail -n2; done
>>> extracts/ <<<
Total Objects: 23
   Total Size: 10633858646
>>> hackathon/ <<<
Total Objects: 2
   Total Size: 10004
>>> home/ <<<
Total Objects: 102
   Total Size: 1421736087
```

Comment: This does not give the deleted objects size?

Comment: Thank you @debugme ! I used the one-line version. You saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

If they're throttling you too 1000 keys per request, I'm not certain how PowerShell is going to help, but if you want to size of a bunch of folders, something like this should do it.

Save the following in a file called Get-FolderSize.ps1:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$True, Mandatory=$True)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [System.String]
    $Path
)

function Get-FolderSize ($_ = (get-item .))  {
  Process {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    #? { $_.FullName -notmatch "\\email\\?" }  <-- Exlcude folders.
    $length = (Get-ChildItem $_.fullname -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Folder ($_.FullName)
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Length ($length)
     Write-Output $obj
  }
}

Function Class-Size($size)
{

    IF($size -ge 1GB)
    {
        "{0:n2}" -f  ($size / 1GB) + " GB"
    }
    ELSEIF($size -ge 1MB)
    {
        "{0:n2}" -f  ($size / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
    ELSE
    {
        "{0:n2}" -f  ($size / 1KB) + " KB"
    }
}

Get-ChildItem $Path | Get-FolderSize | Sort-Object -Property Length -Descending | Select-Object -Property Folder, Length | Format-Table -Property Folder, @{ Label="Size of Folder" ; Expression = {Class-Size($_.Length)} }
```

Usage: .\Get-FolderSize.ps1 -Path \path\to\your\folders